Roofing work - slate-to-slate join - small cuts of slate used to fill gaps
I've just had a re-roof of my 1930s mid-terrace in the UK. The work involved (roughly) the following:

remove all existing slates and ridge tiles

replace horizontal battens and lay roofing felt

put back 'good' slates and replace 'bad' slates with 'good' reclaimed
slates

rebed ridge tiles


A Velux window was also replaced.

The only thing that's concerning me is the slates near the joins with my neighbours' roofs. I guess I was expecting a seamless transition of slates as that's how it was before (at least I think - there was a fair amount of moss or something, limiting visibility). Instead there are these small pieces of slate (maybe ⅕ of the width of the others) filling the apparent gaps, only on the left side, front and back pitches. I think these were the areas they worked on last.
I am not a roofer, so I can't really judge whether this is to be expected. Is using these smaller cuts of slate normal practice?
In the image, cast your eye down from where the two chimney flashing pieces meet, and you should should see what I'm referring to. Sorry for the poor quality image; my phone's camera isn't the best. The image might present larger if you right click it, and choose 'Open image in new tab', if you have that option.

This is just an opinion - I am not a roofer.  The short sections of slate have to go somewhere.  In the middle of the roof is preferable to having them along the edge.  And there is a stagger to them - every other row.  One option would have been for the roofer to place some of the short pieces randomly along the roof.  Another would have been to use 2 slate shingles cut to (say) 2/3 the normal length to make up for the ~1-1/3 needed at the transition.

@SteveSh - Thanks for your reply. The fact that there are small gaps to fill in the first place: do you think this is unavoidable given the slates used were of mixed origin/size and assuming the previous roof didn't have such a break in the pattern? I'm basically trying to verify the quality of the workmanship, if you catch my drift.

With any roof, and with almost all shingle-like roofing products, you're going to have "short" shingles someplace.  The only time you might not is if your roof's width just happens to a even multiple of the width of the shingle.  And even in that case you're going to have partial shingles because of the stagger that's used to offset the joints between shingles, row to row.

Thank you, @SteveSh. It's reassuring to get a second opinion.
